# Passing parameter from Modal dialog to Controller Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog in MVC3 where im passing a parameter to the controller like this:

```
$("#SelectedCSIDivisionCodes").live("click", function () {
        var ID = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCSICodes", "CSICodes")',
            data: { divisionID: ID },
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr);
                alert(status);
                alert(error);
                // you may need to handle me if the json is invalid
                // this is the ajax object
            },
            success: function (json) {
                alert("Data Returned: " + json);
            }
        });

        //            $.getJSON(, { divisionID: ID }, function (data) {
        //                alert(data);
        //            });

    });
```

And I'm receiving the parameter like this:

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetCSICodes(string divisionID)
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(divisionID);
        var csiCodes = (from c in EFProject.CSICode
                        where c.DivisionID == ID
                        select c).OrderBy(x => x.CSICodeID);

        List<SelectListItem> codes = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var code in csiCodes)
        {
            codes.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = code.CSICodeID.ToString(), Text = code.Code + " " + code.Name });

        }

        return Json(codes.AsEnumerable(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The ajax call works fine but its not detecting the parameter value in the controller. In other words, I'm getting null in the variable divisionID only in the controller. I used firefox to see if im setting a value and it seems that it is doing it because it returns this URL: 
 GET http://localhost:1925/CSICodes/GetCSICodes?divisionID%5B%5D=2 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 95690ms]

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: The url should end divisionID=2 not divisionID[]=2. What does ID equal when you debug it in your javascript?

Comment: the control is ListBoxFor helper. When i do an alert($(this).val()) I get a number like 2 for example. I really dont know how to debug it in firefox.

Comment: I would place a breakpoint on the line after ID is set (your ajax call) and then examine what ID was set. The url you described is what would happen if it thought ID was an array with one value in it set to two.

Comment: You were right, I was calling an array of object with just one value and I got confused with the alert value, which made me think I was returning a single value. Once I did a .each, I could catch the right value. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help, I made it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Action is expecting a parameter of type string, but its getting a parameter of an array type.

Url should end divisionID=2, instead it's ending divisionID[]=2 (an array with 1 value of 2).

In certain circumstances, it's possible for the val() function to return an array. See http://api.jquery.com/val/ for details.